# SQL Server Express Uninstall / Enterprise Install Issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

I need help installing SQL Server 2005 Enterprise edition.I really need to remove the current SQL Server 2005.installation that is no longer on my Add/Remove software list but yet
still installed on the machine.

I tried to uninstall SQL Server Express / Developer Edition but it
only removed it from my Add/Remove software list.  It returned
immediately but did NOT actually remove the product.  (I'm now in a
bad state.)

i tried to install SQL Server 2005 Enterprise and its says I'm blocked
as all components are already installed - but they are not.

How can I remove all instance of previous one and install clean Enterprise edition on my server
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing, try the manual un-installation instructions, found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967).

If that doesn't work, you could try the Windows Installer Cleanup tool, found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301). It says its only for Office products, but I've had good luck with many other things.